# How to use echo inside array subscript

Tags: php

```
<?php
                $i=0;
                if( $free_form_fields != '' ) :
                  foreach ($free_form_fields as $fields) 
                  {
                    $parameters = json_decode($fields->parameters);
                    // echo $i;
                    echo "{$form_field_order[$i]}";
                    // if($form_field_order[$i] == $fields->id)
                    // {  
                      echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id={$fields->id}>{$parameters->label}</li>";
                    // }
                    $i = $i+1;
                  } 
                endif;
              ?>
```

I want to check something like this `if($form_field_order[$i] == $fields->id)`

but it is giving me an error

```
> Undefined offset: 2
```

so basically how can i access the $i th value (0,1...) of array $from_field_order?

**Edit**

```
print_r($form_field_order);die(); gives an array

Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 1 )
```

Comment: What is `$form_field_order`?

Comment: what is `$fields->parameters` as $fields is variable from foreach loop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Looping through arrays with for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954691/php-looping-through-arrays-with-for-loop)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293896/php-array-printing-using-a-loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array contains only two elements (0,1 indexed). It tries to access index 2 and throws this error as it is not existing. So Put a condition to check if the element exists using `isset($form_field_order[$i])` before accessing that

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
                $i=0;
                if( count($free_form_fields) > 0 ) :
                  foreach ($free_form_fields as $fields) 
                  {
                    $parameters = json_decode($fields->parameters);
                    // echo $i;
                    echo $form_field_order[$i];
                    // if($form_field_order[$i] == $fields->id)
                    // {  
                      echo "<li class='ui-state-default' id={$fields->id}>{$parameters->label}</li>";
                    // }
                    $i = $i+1;
                  } 
                endif;
              ?>
```